# Set belongings in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I'm intending to conduct an optimization in which I will find the minimum route between some supply nodes and demand nodes. For this I have a set of companies C. These has some supply nodes and demand nodes they "control", for instance stock locations and factories. However, other companies are allowed to deduct products from other companies stocks, and return these to their own demand nodes.

For this I would like to define some set of supply nodes which company c (in C) controls, and some demand nodes of the same type.
I'm thinking that subsets etc. should not be valid (unless I think wrong), as it has to include elements in both C and these nodes. As an example I want company c in C to control supply nodes I, and company c2 in C to control supply nodes G and so on. Can this be achieved in AMPL?

Regards,
Cenderze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multidimensional set for this:

```
set C;
set SupplyNodes;
set CompanySupplies within {C, SupplyNodes};
```

where the second index of `CompanySupplies` represents supplies controlled by company `c in C`, i.e. `setof{(c, n) in CompanySupplies: c == c2} == G`.

Alternatively, you can use an indexed set:

```
set CompanySupplies{C} within SupplyNodes;
```

where`CompanySupplies[c]` represents supplies controlled by company `c in C`.

Comment: How is it possible to "combine" these sets? For instance company c owns a couple of supply points, but I am interested into knowing if it is a more optimal solution by allowing the company c to deduct supply from, say, any supply point within the system, but still "keep the supply belongingness to said company". The latter would be necessary for, for instance, constructing restraints on how much supply can be deducted from each company's supply node set.

Comment: You can get a set of supply nodes for all companies using a `setof` expression `setof{(c,n) in CompanySupplies} n` if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Similarly, for an indexed set `union {c in C} CompanySupplies[c]` gives a set of supply nodes for all companies.